# How to implement this UI

Tags: iphone

Just curious if the tab bar UI element in screenshots is some built in class or customized.
If it is customized, then please give me a hint on what classes I might check to have something like that.

The first screenshot is initial tab bar. When I tap on the last icon the tab bar smoothly(animated) resize itself as on second screenshot. If I press the edit button the icons are shaking(as on iPhone home) and I'm able to arrange them.

first

[tab bar http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/3899/photo2aw.jpg](http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/3899/photo2aw.jpg)

second

[more buttons http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/5673/photo3kq.jpg](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/5673/photo3kq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabbar in the top image could just be a standard tabbar with a non-standard color scheme.

The bottom image is a custom element most likely implemented in an UIActionSheet.

Gotta say, this is a butt ugly UI using non-standard (and therefore confusing) elements. I wouldn't suggest trying to emulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's custom. You might just want to look at subclassing UIView and putting a bunch of buttons it stored in a NSArray. That way, when you re-arange them, you just have to move the objects to a new position in the array.

You should be able to achieve the shaking by using simple UIView animations.

Comment: Thanks. Can anyone elaborate more? How about the gray bar with 2 buttons?